# Execute jQuery script after submitting a form

Tags: php, jquery, submit, jquery-callback

I want to execute a jQuery script after submitting a form. The jQuery script it's only a line that will fade In a hidden  that will show if the e-mail have been sent or not sent.

The PHP code is at the top of the file and I don't know if staying the PHP code at the top is the problem but I tried moving de PHP above the jquery script but it doesn't work.

EDIT:

Now I have that code in my index.php

```
        $(document).ready(function) {
            $('form').submit(function) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "mail.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
                        email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                        msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val()
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#result').html(response);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

In mail.php I have that other code

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

if(mail('test@test.com', $name, $msg)) {
    echo 'Pass!';
} else {
    echo 'Fail!';
}
```

When I executed it nothing happens and the URL shows the data that I wrote in the inputs but any message appears.

Comment: can you please show us how your relevant jQuery code look like?

Comment: When the form is submitted, the page reloads, and all your javascript is basically lost.

Comment: Read about AJAX. submit button -> onClick="sendEmail()" -> prevent default -> get form data -> send it to the server side -> get the result and show the hidden element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example for processing a form with AJAX. Notice the IDs: `#emailForm` is the ID of the form, and `#out` is the ID of some HTML element (such as a `div` or `p`) where you want to display the result. The function email.php is your server side script to send the email and return the result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emailForm').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "email.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
            msg: $('input[name="msg"]').val()
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(responseText){
            $('#out').html(responseText);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

On the server side, email.php (or whatever you want to call it) processes the data and sends the email. The data can be retrieved from the $_POST array. After sending or attempting to send the email, email.php can simply echo the result to be inserted in the HTML element with the id of "out."

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
//PUT CODE HERE FOR SENDING EMAIL

if ($success){
    echo "Email sent with success!";
} else {
    echo "Unable to send your email at this time. Please try again later.";
}
```

The output should appear in the HTML element:

```
<div id="out">Email sent with success!</div>
```

Comment: I tried to use the example you said me but I don't receive anything from sendmail.php

Comment: @Alexbha - I updated my answer with new code that I tested, and it works. Please note that this code uses post, so the data must be retrieved from the $_POST array.

Comment: I edited my question to post the code that I have now, but I don't have any message as response

Comment: @Alexbha - Did you change the $_GETs to $_POSTs in the PHP file? Any error in your PHP code will cause it not to work. I ran the code that I posted, and it worked fine. Also it's good to use Firbug or Fiddler to see what's happening with your HTTP requests.

Comment: I wrote them. I found the problem, it was missing a parenthesis and now it works. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onSubmit` attribute in `form` tag

e.g.

```
  <form name="anything" id="anything" onSubmit="functionname();" >
```

**or** the other option is `onClick` of `Submit` button

```
  <input type="submit" onClick="functionname();" value="SUBMIT FORM" />
```

I personally preffer 1st method

Comment: functionname() will be executed before the form is submited. BTW, submitting form will cause the page to refresh. But wait, maybe it is what OP is looking for after all.

Comment: why not use jQuery .on() or submit(), instead of inline script?

Comment: Mmm...and if I want execute it after submitting the form and when the function mail() was executed correctly?

Comment: And what will be the result? A blink before submitting. Something like "your email was sent." but maybe the email will be not sent successfully? And page refreshes without any information...

Comment: if you want to perform a jQuery only after the form submission then you have to use ajax for submission  or the other way is to pass a extra parameter in submission and listen to that in jQuery and perform action